# Bug in gmaven-plugin execute goal (using by groovy)

Tags: maven, groovy, git-log, gmaven-plugin, gmaven

I try to set system property using by gmaven-plugin in build time.

but property result is diffrent in linux and window build environment.

In linux environment, it have double quote string. but window is not.

why is result different? Could you answer me please?

```
build result
linux : ### commitId : "8def4294ccb346795bd9682b5bcb9174bc64d78f"
window : ### commitId : 8def4294ccb346795bd9682b5bcb9174bc64d78f
```

pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <script>git log -n1 --pretty=format:"%H" web/</script>
                </properties>
                <source>
                    def command = project.properties.script
                    def process = command.execute()
                    process.waitFor()
                    project.properties.setProperty('commitId', process.in.text.trim())
                    println '### commitId : ' + project.properties.commitId
                </source>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Does git give different output on windows from Linux?

Comment: @tim_yates I did testing. but it is same. I guess. it is related  <source> and <script>. but i don't know exactly reason.

Comment: @tim_yates I found .beacause of this format(--pretty=format:"%H" ), it disappear double quote in window environment. but it exist in linux.

Answer (score -1):

groovy script have a problem.

so need to split parameter like this.

def a = ['git', 'log', "-n1" , "--pretty=format:%H", 'web/'].execute().text.trim()